# `bookdown`/`rmarkdown`/`knitr`: Non-code sequential processing howto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Programatically my `bookdown` project proceeds as follows:

1. Reading in raw data - produces all kind of stats.
2. Data preprocessing (logarithmization, normalization, imputation) - produces various plots for monitoring the population-level defects incurred.
3. PCA for analysis QC - produces plots for PCA and loadings-dominating data points.
4. Differential expression analysis - produces volcano plots and plots characterizing prominent differentially expressed features.
5. Overrepresentation analysis of the differentially expressed features from 4. in various biological ontology systems - produces example bar plots for enriched categories.

I have analysis and narrative nicely integrated using `bookdown`, enabling efficient on fly discarding of temporary (sizable) data sets/`ggplot2` objects (pre/post transformation data etc.).

HOWEVER: The target audience is mostly/only interested in 4. & 5., leading me to the aspired to following structure:

> 4., 5., Appendix(1., 2., 3.)

Is there any other way but precomputing 1.-5. and then revisiting in the targeted order - I would prefer to avoid accumulating all those `ggplot2` objects in memory if at all possible.

Comment: X-posted @ https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/602

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Split steps 1-3 and 4-5 into two speparate `*.Rmd` files, say `123.Rmd` and `45.Rmd`.
2. Add a code chunk to the beginning of `45.md` that knits `123.Rmd` to `123.md`:

```` ```{r knit123, include = FALSE}
knitr::knit("123.Rmd", output = "123.md")
``` ````

This will generate the output of steps 1-3 in Markdown and make all the objects created thereby available to steps 4-5.

3. Add a code chunk to the end of `45.Rmd` that reads `123.md` prints its content:

```` ```{r include123, results = "asis"}
cat(readLines("123.md"), sep = "\n")
``` ````

The `results = "asis"` will prevent any further processing as it is already valid Markdown.

4. Knit `45.Rmd` to whatever target format you want.

---

***edit (1)***:

**TL;DR**: Instead of storing the object from steps 1-3 in memory throughout steps 4-5 in order to print them afterwards, print them first and store the results on disk.

---

***edit (2):***

Since you explicitely mentioned bookdown: I would not be surprised if there was a YAML option to include a Markdown file at the end of the knitting process (something like `include-after: 123.md`); but I don't know for sure from the top of my head and I'm too lazy to look it up myself. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have included this solution into my project successfully now!

Comment: @balin: Great to hear - happy to help. Don't forget to close your github issue if it's no longer an issue. ;-)